# simple CakePHP router to JSON

Tags: cakephp-1.3

In CakePHP 1.3 I have this router in *routes.php*:

```
Router::connect('/listing/*', array('controller' => 'items', 'action' => 'index'));
```

My question is, how can I create an `html-form` with submit action to *www.mysite.com/listing.json*?

This is the form I currently have in the folder *app/views/items/index.cpt*.

```
$this->Form->create( 'Item' ); // HTML: <form action="/listing" method="post">
```

I tried to change the submit-action to "*listing.json*", but it didn't work because "*/items/*" is being prepend, and I don't want that.

```
$this->Form->create( 'Item', array( 'action' => 'listing.json' ) ); // HTML: <form action="/items/listing.json" method="post">
```

++

In other words, I want the form action to be like this: any idea?

```
<form action="listing.json" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to configure your router to handle .json.

`Router::parseExtensions('json');`

Then do the form creation like this.

`$this->Form->create( 'Item', array('url' => array('controller'=>'items', 'action'=>'index', 'ext' => 'json')));`

I believe this would work.

But... There's a problem with what you are trying to do. Even though you mark the submit URL as a *.json, it doesn't mean you will be posting a json request. With this change, the only thing you would be doing is posting a html form to a url named as a *.json.